# MethodBase.Invoke to Web Api from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, system.reflection

I am using Reflection to invoke methods from a Web API, but when extracting the constructor, it returns a URL instead of the constructor information, which causes an error when using `MethodBase.Invoke` with the following error message:

[image]

Is it possible to use reflection with a Web API?

My code:

[image]

If I use Reflection with an object within my project or namespace, it returns the information correctly, and the invocation works fine.

Comment: _"it returns a URL"_  - what returns URL, where? I don't see any urls here.